# BURG installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, burg

I've been reading about the BURG bootloader as a replacement for GRUB2.

If I install BURG, will it overwrite GRUB and all of its settings? How will things work, and how do I install themes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grub is basically the same thing as burg.  It's just more appealing looking.  Here's what I recommend:

Goggle: grub customizer

It's a Linux program.  I figure your on Linux if you have grub2, and by the fact that your on a Ubuntu q&a site.  Anyway, that is pretty easy to install.

Once it is installed, open it up.  In one of the drop down menus, there is an option that says "change environment".  Click.  Where it says grub2, deselect that and select burg.  Hit okay.  Now go to file>install to mbr.  This will install burg to your master boot record.  Now you can edit some of the entries if you wish.

Now when you are booting up, and the burg screen shows up, press [t].  Then use the arrow keys, and select an option.  To install new themes, listen up.

Download a them via handy-dandy Internet.  Go to your computer folder, the to boot>Burt>themes.  Here u see lots of folders.  Just paste in one of those downloaded themes.  If the theme has icons, make sure you put those in the icons folder.  You will probably have to edit the burg file for burg to recognize the theme.

You say you have been reading about it.  That would infer you know how to read.  And type.  And google.  You should consult this thing know as the World Wide Web before asking here.  There are hundreds of tutorials on how to install burg, or the themes, or what burg even is.  Sorry chap, but your supposed to do your research first, ask questions later.

Answer (score 0):

[BURG stands for Brand-new Universal loadeR from GRUB. It’s based on GRUB and adds features like new object format and configurable menu system.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Burg)

**Change of GRUB to BURG**

[image: GRUB TO BURG]

For Ubuntu, we first add repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
```

We update database

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install the package BURG

```
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
```

*Once installed, we will have to answer some questions of settings, such as where to install it. It is important to install it on the same partition where we have installed our operating system. Otherwise, we could do that any other system could not start.*

[image: burg-conf]

Select the installation disk,It is usually in `/dev/sda`  (the first hard disk).If not sure of where to install it, do not do, looking for information.

to install it in `/dev/sda` run

```
sudo burg-install /dev/sda
```

and finally update with

```
sudo update-burg
```

Before rebooting we can emulate the system startup screen and configure the bootloader as you wish using the following command:

```
sudo burg-emu
```

If we find a theme that you like, we can install more with Grub Customizer. To install it in terminal type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

You can configure new options, such as the background or add graphic elements, from the tab "Appereance settings". Also we will allow download new themes.

If, for the reason that we want to use GRUB 2, we just have to open a terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge burg burg-themes
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo update-grub
```